# Dividing Data Frame rows by different values

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I've got a simple Data Frame.  I want to divide each row by a different value (in this case, my rows are a sum of weekly data and I want to divide by the number of weeks in a month).  When I do the following nothing happens, I just get the same values prior to the division attempt. I tried using a constant in the divide function as well, but same results. Obviously I'm missing a step.  Any thoughts?

```
number_of_weeks = [4,4,5,1]

for i in range(len(df_Plot.index)):
    df_Plot.iloc[[i][:]].div(number_of_weeks[i])
```

```
               A       B       C       D
Date                                      
2023-01-31  0.0325  3.6375  0.0000   0.025
2023-02-28  0.0300  1.7000  0.0000   0.000
2023-03-31  0.0000  0.4375  0.1875   0.000
2023-04-30  0.0250  0.5500  0.4250   0.000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```python
df_Plot = df_Plot.div(number_of_weeks, axis=0)
```

... or this:

```python
df_Plot = (df_Plot.T / number_of_weeks).T
```

Output:

```
                   A         B       C        D
Date
2023-01-31  0.008125  0.909375  0.0000  0.00625
2023-02-28  0.007500  0.425000  0.0000  0.00000
2023-03-31  0.000000  0.087500  0.0375  0.00000
2023-04-30  0.025000  0.550000  0.4250  0.00000
```

Although there's no need to iterate as in the sample code in your question,  since `div()` allows for vectorized operation as above, it's possible to get the same result using iteration like this:

```python
for i in range(len(df_Plot)):
    df_Plot.iloc[i,:] = df_Plot.iloc[i,:].div(number_of_weeks[i])
```

Comment: Well.. talk about making something much harder than it needed to be!  Thanks.